# gcloud install kubectl fails on MacBook M1

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, apple-m1

I modified the following Dockerfile to use arm binaries so it works on my M1 MacBook Pro, the original works fine on a MacBook Pro i5.

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64/v8 alpine:latest

RUN apk --no-cache add \
    ack~3 \
    bash~5 \
    curl~7 \
    htop~3 \
    jq~1.6 \
    make~4.3 \
    nano~5 \
    python3~3 \
    tree~1.8 \
    util-linux~2

ARG CLOUD_SDK_VERSION=367.0.0
ENV PATH /google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH

RUN curl -O https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-${CLOUD_SDK_VERSION}-darwin-arm.tar.gz && \
    tar xzf google-cloud-sdk-${CLOUD_SDK_VERSION}-darwin-arm.tar.gz && \
    rm google-cloud-sdk-${CLOUD_SDK_VERSION}-darwin-arm.tar.gz && \
    gcloud components list && \
    gcloud components install kubectl
```

The last step `gcloud components install kubectl` fails with the following error.

> WARNING: The platform specific binary does not exist for components
> [kubectl].
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.components.install) The following components
> are unknown [kubectl].

Comment: Based on the error prompted you might have missed something or repository you can check this Google documentation https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/install. Or this Kubernetes documentation on installing https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-macos/

Comment: I think the issue is that `gcloud` is not able to detect the platform where it is running so not able to know which version of `kubectl` to download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the platform to amd64 and it worked!

> FROM --platform=linux/amd64 alpine:latest